# global variable is not changing in this java code but I am changing it

Tags: java, android

Please say where I am doing wrong for varCount

```
public class Ver extends AppCompatActivity {

    ....   
    static int varCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver);


        ...
    }

    public void submitNumber(View view) {
        if (!validate()) {
            Log.d("check52", "" + mobile);
            return;
        } else {
            submitRequest();
        }

    }

    private void submitRequest() {

            ....
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                   //here I put Log.d and seen that here it is showing varCount=0
                    checkVerify(a, b);
                   //here unknown thing is happening.. checkVerify is being called but the Log statement written here is showing varCount as 0. And after sometime it shows in varCount when checkVerify method calls completely and then it's changing from 0 to 1  
                    if(varCount == 1){

                        send(mobile);
                    }
                    else{

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"jsbvsj",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void checkVerify(String a, String b) {
        ...
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        if(...){
                          ...
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.d("checkp33",""+varCount);
                            varCount++;
                            Log.d("checkp39",""+varCount);
                        }
                    } else {
                     .....   
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Please say as I don't know where I am getting this little thing wrong. I want to perform some actions on varCount if 0 and different one if flag is 1. I am changing varCount to 1 but it remains as 0. Please tell me someone that why? Where should I change

Comment: Try making it `volatile` like `static volatile int varCount = 0;`.

Comment: still not working

Comment: The only place I can see where `varCount` is changed is `varCount++;` that is dependent on `if(...){`. As you don't provide the information about `...` your question lacks details and is flaggable as such. Also we cannot tell if `task.isSuccessful()` is ever `true` but it could be the reason. Please provide enough details so your question actually becomes answerable.

Comment: Yes, in the else{} it's written as varCount++
I tried to put Log.d and checked in the logcat that it is changing the value to 1. After that control moves to the method from which checkVerify is called. After reaching there, again I put Log.d and saw the value changed to 0 again.